# How to disable hawt.io authentication?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, hawtio

I used spring boot, hawt.io, camel to test hawt.io dashboard

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.10.RELEASE'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
}

dependencies {

// Spring actuator, log4j2
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")

//Spring web
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"){
exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
compile("org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jaas")
compile("org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http")

compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator")

//hawtio
compile("io.hawt:hawtio-springboot:1.5.10")
compile("io.hawt:hawtio-core:1.5.10")
```

and i had disabled authentication via

> `hawtio.authenticationEnabled=false`

Here is the log:

```
18:00:13.489 [main] DEBUG ConfigManager - Property noCredentials401 is set to value false
18:00:13.490 [main] DEBUG ConfigManager - Property realm is set to value karaf
18:00:13.490 [main] DEBUG ConfigManager - Property role is set to value null
18:00:13.490 [main] DEBUG ConfigManager - Property roles is set to value null
18:00:13.490 [main] DEBUG ConfigManager - Property rolePrincipalClasses is set to value 
18:00:13.490 [main] DEBUG ConfigManager - Property authenticationEnabled is set to value false
18:00:13.490 [main] DEBUG ConfigManager - Property noCredentials401 is set to value false
18:00:13.490 [main] DEBUG ConfigManager - Property authenticationContainerDiscoveryClasses is set to value io.hawt.web.tomcat.TomcatAuthenticationContainerDiscovery
18:00:13.490 [main] INFO  AuthenticationFilter - Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS authentication disabled
18:00:13.500 [main] DEBUG ConfigManager - Property sessionTimeout is set to value 1800
18:00:13.500 [main] INFO  LoginServlet - hawtio login is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout
```

When i open url http://localhost:8091/hawtio/index.html, it always be redirected to http://localhost:8091/hawtio/index.html#/login

How can i disable authentication?

According https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/1963, the issue should be fixed on 6 Dec 2015, but it's still there.

And according those 404 errors, it seems all requests are handled by spring mvc DispatcherServlet, and those servlets registered in `HawtioManagementContextConfiguration` are not worked as expected.

```
18:07:52.821 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/hawtio/keycloak/enabled]
18:07:52.821 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /hawtio/keycloak/enabled
18:07:52.821 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/hawtio/keycloak/enabled]
18:07:52.821 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/hawtio/keycloak/enabled] are [/hawtio/**, /**]
18:07:52.821 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/hawtio/keycloak/enabled] are {}
18:07:52.822 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/hawtio/keycloak/enabled] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], ServletContext resource [/app/], class path resource [hawtio-static/], class path resource [hawtio-static/app/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@244d7ca5]]] and 1 interceptor
18:07:52.822 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/hawtio/keycloak/enabled] is: -1
18:07:52.824 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
18:07:52.824 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /error
18:07:52.825 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
18:07:52.825 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
18:07:52.833 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG ContentNegotiatingViewResolver - Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
18:07:52.833 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG BeanNameViewResolver - No matching bean found for view name 'error.html'
18:07:52.838 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG ContentNegotiatingViewResolver - Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@150fc7a7] based on requested media type 'text/html'
18:07:52.838 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@150fc7a7] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
18:07:52.886 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
18:07:52.887 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
18:07:52.887 [qtp1016881733-22] DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
18:07:52.965 [qtp1016881733-47] DEBUG DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/favicon.ico]
18:07:52.965 [qtp1016881733-47] DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/favicon.ico] are [/**/favicon.ico]
18:07:52.965 [qtp1016881733-47] DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/favicon.ico] are {}
18:07:52.965 [qtp1016881733-47] DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/favicon.ico] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], class path resource []], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@ec04917]]] and 1 interceptor
18:07:52.965 [qtp1016881733-47] DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/favicon.ico] is: -1
18:07:52.969 [qtp1016881733-47] DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
18:07:52.969 [qtp1016881733-47] DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Comment: Thx @Marged suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the reason is that you just forget the final required step to use Hawtio with Spring Boot. You need this line in your `application.properties`:

```
endpoints.jolokia.sensitive = false
```

Without this setting Jolokia endpoint always returns 401 for unauthenticated requests, thus causing redirects to the login page.

You can also refer to a working example of unauthenticated Hawtio with Spring Boot here:
https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/master/hawtio-sample-springboot

By the way, Hawtio 2.0 will be released very soon.

Comment: I had this line in application.properties :

`endpoints.jolokia.sensitive=false
`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found the root cause is that

> management.port != server.port

I referenced this one [SpringBootCamelStarter](https://github.com/gpimblott/SpringBootCamelStarter), i also used **8095** for management port and **8091** for server port, and i used the normal server port **8091** to access it, that's the issue, i should use management port **8095** to access hawtio dashboard. here is the clear description:https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/2.x/examples/springboot